# Python CSV: selecting specific row/column ranges

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, csv

I've been caught up on this for far longer than I'd care to admit. I'm working on one of my first projects, and it'll be fed new CSV data daily.

The CSVs are consistent, all from the same trusted source. However the data I'm interested in starts on row 30 and varies in length; and in particular I'm interested in the 2nd, 4th, and 8th columns.

I've tried using Pandas; however that gets caught up by the data sitting in rows 1-29 (much of which is blank).

How do I read these specific ranges and copy to array or JSON?

Comment: I suggest you paste an excerpt of your data. Not sure how anyone can answer this question without knowing what your data looks like. Also see *[mcve]*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're okay with `pandas`, you can do:

```
import pandas as pd

filename = 'path/to/your.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows=30, usecols=[2, 4, 8])
```

`skiprows` can be an integer (the number of rows to skip, from the top), a list of rows to exclude, or a boolean callable that gets called on each row index.

`usecols` can be a list of indices, a list of column names, or a boolean callable that gets called on each column name.

Check out the documentation for [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: The second question `How do I read these specific ranges and copy to array or JSON?` is unclear (to me)

Comment: You know, I'd read those read_csv docs atleast 3 times in this search... I didn't know you could do indexes in usecols. Thought it'd only take column header names. 

This is great. And exactly what I was looking for. It'll get me going. Thank you very much for your help.